# How can I display the last selected accordion after reload/refresh

Tags: dojo

I am using Dojo and Zend Framework. I have a bunch of accordions on the left side of the page with each accordion serving as a container for related functionalities. If say a user is working on accordion B and performs a function that reloads or refreshes the page, I want to have accordion B selected after refresh instead the original default. How do I get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set persist to true for your accordion. See http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.5/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.

Basically you need to do either:

```
new dijit.layout.AccordionContainer({ persist: true });
```

or

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" persist="true">
 ...
</div>
```

Very simple working example at http://telliott.net/dojoExamples/dojo-persistingAccordion.html

Comment: ha! sorry about that, I'll be more prompt in future :)

Comment: mrtom before your answer i had to use cookies like so:                dojo.subscribe("leftPane-selectChild", this, function(pane)
                {
                    cookieValue = pane.id;
                    dojo.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
                });

                if (dojo.cookie(cookieName))
                {
                    dijit.byId("leftPane").selectChild(dojo.cookie(cookieName));
                }

Comment: well, all dojo does is use cookies under the hood. So your solution isn't wrong, just unnecessary complex :)

See http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/tags/release-1.5.0/dijit/layout/StackContainer.js#L56